# Solve for X where Sum(A.X+C).(A.X + C) = X

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am trying to solve for X (vector of dimension n):

$\Sigma_{i=1}^n(AX+C)_i(AX + C) = X$

where:
C = is a constant vector dimension n
A = is a diagonal invertible matrix [n,n]

Comment: Sorry is that a sum or what? What is it running over if it is? Otherwise, what is sigma? Also you can enclose math in $\$$ and use LaTeX syntax to format your posts.

Comment: sigma is sum - i mean the sum of the element of the vector - thanks

Comment: So if the left side is a sum across the elements of the vector, how can it be equal to a vector, $X$?

Comment: Σ(AX+C) is a scalar which depends on X - and (AX+C) is a vector

Comment: Oh I think I get it now

Comment: What is $\Sigma$? What is the connection between the title and the question - I see trace nowhere in the body text.

Comment: I forgot to modify the title - i just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $A$ is invertible and put $Y=AX+C$. Then $(\sum_iY_i)Y=A^{-1}(Y-C)$. This a system of $n$ equations of degree $2$ in the $n$ unknowns $(Y_i)_i$. Generically (when $A,C$ are full random matrices or also when $A$ is a diagonal random matrix) it seems to have $n+1$ complex solutions.